# Two legal questions on Ethereum and Smart Contracts

Tags: evm

1- Who answers before the judicial instances by any problem in the platform of Ethereum?

2- How does the decentralized platform of Ethereum to annul and render ineffective any smart contracts on which falls a judicial sentence of nullity?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're taking the term smart **contract** too literally. They aren't legal contracts, they're just programs that run on the  blockchain trustlessly. There is no such thing as "judicial sentence of nullity"